# element.all(by.repeater....).get(0).clicks fails after upgrade from protractor 1.7 to 2.1

Tags: javascript, protractor

We're working on automating tests using jasmine/protractor/selenium/chromedriver.
After a recent upgrade from protractor 1.7 to 2.1 certain commands now fail.

html:
the pages we're working with contain an ng-repeat item in directoryList. The first page contains a list of facilities and the next page contains a list of services within the facility chosen.

html for the directoryList is the same on both pages other than the actual strings naming each list item. The names are populated by a call internal to our application which returns the list of facilities or services as appropriate for the page.  The link for the first item on the first page is

```
<a class="directory-link"
ng-click="vm.directoryLink( item )" 
href="javascript:void(0)"> 
<span class="fa fa-angle-right directory-forward-button"></span> 
<p class="directory-entry-p">Facility 1</p> 
</a>
```

xpath is `//*[@id="right-main-content-container"]/section/div/fang-directory-list/div/div[1]/div/div/a`

our test code clicks on the first element by doing

```
element.all( by.repeater( 'item in directoryList' ) ).get( 0 ).click();
```

in 1.7 that click takes us to the second page with the list of services. The html is identical except for the string being displayed - we're still using ng-repeat item in directoryList. The directoryList just contains different elements on the new page. We repeat the above statement to click on the first service, and it takes us to yet another page (as expected).

In 2.1 we can't even click on the first facility without getting an error:

```
 Failed: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (787, 148). Other element would receive the click: `<p class="directory-entry-p">...</p>`
```

If we change the test code to use the xpath:

```
element( by.xpath( '//*[@id="right-main-content-container"]/section/div/fang-directory-list/div/div[1]/div/div/a') ).click();
```

we get a warning:

```
WARNING - more than one element found for locator By.xpath("//*[@id=\"right-main-content-container\"]/section/div/fang-directory-list/div/div[1]/div/div/a") - the first result will be used
```

The xpath for element 1 of page 1 and element 1 of page 2 are identical. If I add console.log message to print out the number of facilities I get the correct answer.  If I add a console.log message to print the number of services in the facility I get a number equal to the number of facilities plus 2 * the number of services for facility 1. This plus the above warning lead me to think that protractor is concatenating the directoryLists from each page together in some way.

This feels like a possible bug in protractor. We can't go back to 1.7 because we need the features in 2.1 for test automation.  Is anyone seeing this in their code?  We have tried a lot of options without success. The usual element-is-not-clickable suggestions do not work in this case, and we have not found a workaround. Any suggestions?